# Is the function $f\colon \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=x+\sin(x)$ uniformly continuous on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, elementary-functions

I know how to show not uniformly or how to show it is uniformly continuous but not how to differentiate when to know which one to use

Answer (score 6):

$|f'(x)|=|1+cosx|\leq 2$, and thus $f$ is Lipschitz continuous and thus uniformly continuous.

Comment: I've covered the Lipschitz condition in numerical analysis so that makes sense but we haven't used it in real analysis yet which is where this question is from. Is there a way to go about it without using Lipschitz

Comment: Im writing my proof, and when i make the statement that the limits tend to $-\infty$ and $+\infty$, im not sure if i need to prove these statements. i see how plugging it in it is obvious but do i need to prove it?

Comment: No,i think that you don't have to prove this statement for the existance of the limits in the edges of the integral ,because this is a theorem. so i think it's is known

Comment: @Dimitris What about $x^2$? That criteria is not correct.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff $x^2$ is not uniformly continuous in $\Bbb R$. However my statement is wrong.thnx for that.

Comment: @TonyK,$x^2$ is not uniformly continuous in $\Bbb R$. However my statement is wrong.thnx for that.

Answer (score 3):

$|f(x)-f(y)|\\=|x+\sin x-y-\sin y|\\\le|x-y|+|\sin x-\sin y|\\=|x-y|+2\left|\cos\dfrac{x+y}{2}\sin\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right|\\\le\left|x-y\right|+2\left|\sin\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right|\\\le|x-y|+2\left|\dfrac{x-y}{2}\right|\\=2|x-y|$

Thus $f$ is Lipschitz continuous on $\mathbb R$ and hence uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R.$

Comment: A bit easier to use the mean value theorem: $\sin x-\sin y=\cos\xi\cdot(x-y)$ for some $\xi$ between $x$ and $y$, and it follows that $|\sin x-\sin y|\le |x-y|$. This avoids having to verify separately that [$|\sin t|\le|t|$](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/590583/462).

Answer (score 0):

A sum of uniformly continuous functions is uniformly continuous.

Let $f$ and $g$ be uniformly continuous on the same domain. For $\varepsilon>0$ there exist $\delta_1>0$ and $\delta_2>0$ such that

- if $|x-y|<\delta_1$, then $|f(x)-f(y)|<\varepsilon/2$
- if $|x-y|<\delta_2$, then $|g(x)-g(y)|<\varepsilon/2$

Take $\delta=\min\{\delta_1,\delta_2\}$; then, for $|x-y|<\delta$ we have

$$
|f(x)+g(x)-f(y)-g(y)|\le|f(x)-f(y)|+|g(x)-g(y)|<
\frac{\varepsilon}{2}+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}=\varepsilon
$$

I suppose you know that $f(x)=x$ and $g(x)=\sin x$ are uniformly continuous. For $f$ it is obvious; for $g$ it suffices to remember that it is continuous and periodic, so by the Heine-Borel theorem it is uniformly continuous.